# MySQL query needs optimization

Tags: mysql

I have a query that fetches the ID of the product with the lowest price for every model, in a database where the product's price and ID is in one table and the model ID is in an attributes table that's linked to the product via a id_product field.

The issue is that this query currently takes over 40s to run, and seeing as there are only about 1/4 of the total products currently in the table, it needs to run a lot faster to be of any use in the final product.

Here's the query at the moment:

```
SELECT P.id, A.value
FROM  `products` P,  `attributes_values` A
WHERE A.id_product = P.id
AND P.price = ( 
SELECT MIN( P2.price ) 
FROM  `products` P2,  `attributes_values` A2
WHERE A2.id_product = P2.id
AND A2.id_attribute =54
AND A2.value = A.value ) 
AND A.id_attribute =54
GROUP BY A.value
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The expected result is something like this:

```
P.id (product ID) | A.value (model ID)
-----------------------------------------
1245              | AGRIMAX FORCE
1250              | AGRIMAX FORTIS
1255              | AGRIMAX TERIS
1257              | AGRIMAXSIRIO
1908              | ALENZA
1927              | ALENZA PLUS
1259              | AMAX SPARGO
1261              | AMAX TERIS
2                 | ARMORMAXMSD
```

How could I make the query faster without changing the way the tables are set up?

Comment: Are you using indexes? And why do not just order by price DESC instead of selecting from another table?

Comment: Pls add the result of the explain and list the indexes and their fields from all affected tables.

Comment: @SimoneCabrino There are some indexes in both tables, although I haven't created any for this specifically. The attributes_values table has an index on the id_attribute and an index on the id_product. The product table doesn't have any indexes that seem relevant for this query, except that the primary key is the ID.

Also, how could I select the first product of each model by only doing a order by on the price? Handle that directly in PHP afterwards doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: @Shadow Added information in the comment above, hope that helps you guys help me. ;)

Comment: Again, pls share the output of the explain.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a correct answer if you cannot supply information about the tables, but if MySQL is an issue, you can simplify your query in this way

```
SELECT P.id, A.value FROM `products` P, LEFT JOIN `attributes_values` A ON  A.id_product = P.id WHERE A.id_attribute =54 ORDER BY price LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and then, while looping the results, check the prices and breaking the loop when price is different from the one you already parsed.

Your query can be probably quickly speed up by adding an index on the price field...